# Sending HTTP request using Scalatra & Scala

Tags: scala, http-request, scalatra

I have a Scalatra web application, when a user sends a get request to the server, ie. www.example.com/getsomething it routes to the following code:

```
class ExampleServlet extends ScalatraServlet {
   get("/getsomething") { 
    //code here
   }
}
```

In the body of the get I would like to send out another get request to another server and capture the JSON that is sent back eg:

```
var JSONback = GetRequest("www.SomeOtherApi.com/getsomeJSON")
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic needs you could use `scala.io.Source`

```
scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://www.google.de","latin1").mkString
res10: String =
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"     ="de"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

For more sophisticated use cases you can use any http-client-library like:

- Dispatch: 
  http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html
- Http4s
  http://http4s.org/